# Erikativ, Inflektiv (*fragend schau*)

Tags: colloquial, infinitive, contractions

Der Inflektiv bzw. Erikativ ist eine besonders von Erika Fuchs verwendete Übersetzung für die englischen Phrasen in Comics wie *seufz*, *gähn*, *mit den Füßen aufstampf*, *ganz lieb sei*.

In Foren und Chat ist diese Form - auch als Emoticonsynonym - inzwischen in weiter Verwendung.

Gibt es ähnliche Formen auch vor den Comicübersetzungen von 1950?

Answer (score 7):

Was geschriebene Sprache und Literatur betrifft, so fallen mir **Interjektionen** ein, die etwas in diese Richtung darstellen und auch in der Literatur vor 1950 Verwendung fanden.

Interjektionen sind u. a. Wörter eines spontanen Ausdrucks körperlicher oder seelischer Empfindungen wie

- hm, ah ja, aha (Interesse, Zustimmung)
- pfui, bäh, igitt (Ekel)
- hurra, ah, jippi (Freude)

oder Ausrufe wie

- he!
- aber hallo!
- pst!

und Geräuschnachahmungen

- haha, hihi, hehe (Lachen)
- äh, hm, tja (Verzögerungslaute beim Reden)
- miau, wau wau, kikeriki (Tierlaute)
- bumms, klirr, schwups

Etwas ähnliches, auf das man in der Literatur häufig stößt, sind **Lautmalereien**. Bei Wilhelm Busch zum Beispiel findet man folgende Sätze:

> „Schnupdiwup“ entführen Max und Moritz die gebratenen Hühner mit der Angel durch den Kamin
>
> „Ritzeratze“ sägen sie in die „Brücke eine Lücke“
>
> „Rickeracke! Rickeracke! Geht die Mühle mit Geknacke“

Da die Wörter vom Erzähler verwendet werden, haben sie natürlich nicht dieselbe Wirkung wie die in Comic in direkter Rede auftauchenden "seufz", "gähn" etc.

Comment: Aus aktuellem Anlaß sei darauf verwiesen, wie sich "Rickeracke! Rickeracke!" herzallerliebst reimt auf "Zickezacke Hühnerkacke!" - normalerweise nicht mein Sprachgebrauch, aber anläßlich des Todes Loriots, dessen Wirken aber auch nach 1950 datiert, vielleicht erlaubt.