# How do you say "LOL" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm not sure how to say LOL in German. It might be *Lautes Auflachen* or *Laut Lachend*, I'm not positive which.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please? Surely, when one uses the acronym *lol* in German, the intended expansion is still the English phrase, rather than a German substitute for it. On the other hand, if you are referring to expressing the action of laughing out in German, there are various expressions that can be used depending on the context (such as *prusten*).

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/erikativ-inflektiv-fragend-schau?s=2|0.1663 and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7054/chatty-expression-in-german - Answer "Erikativ" and think of *lach!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LOL has become an onomatopoeia in German. So people actually say *lol* or *ell-o-ell*.

Comment: EDIT: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STr_flCNRsY&t=2m23s That clip is running each night on KiKa in an endless loop.

Comment: Rofl, du hast lol gesagt!

Answer (score 9):

In German chats, the [*Erikativ*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/erikativ-inflektiv-fragend-schau) of verbs is used to express actions. Those extralinguistic expressions are set in asterisks ([Ref.](http://www.zeit.de/2000/51/_lach_und_rofl_))

> *lach*

from *lachen* (= laugh)

> *grins* or *g*

from *grinsen* (= grin)

Comment: Und alle so: (::-kicher-::)